# IEC grounding and bonding standard

Tags: ground, standard, ul, wirebonding, iec

Is there an equivalent standard in IEC such as UL 467 or IEEE 837 which talks about the various test procedure for bonding clamps? Is IEC 61914:2015 similar to UL 467?